# How to ignore obj folder using Git under MS Windows

Tags: windows, git, gitignore

I have got following path that I need to exlcude to commit with Git

```
C:\Projects\GitHub\MyProjects\TED\SourceCode\Presentation\REXI.Web\obj
```

Everything is under `C:\Projects\GitHub\` is cloned Git repository.

And at the same folder I have got `.gitignore`

```
C:\Projects\GitHub\.gitignore
```

So which pattern I have to use to exclude `obj` folder?

Thank you!

Comment: Is `GitHub` the cloned Git repository, or `MyProjects`? I would have guessed from the name that it was in fact `TED` that was the repository.

Comment: @JonHanna the `GitHub` is cloned rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj` to ignore all `obj` folders or files ever.

`obj/` to ignore all `obj` folders ever.

`MyProjects/TED/SourceCode/Presentation/REXI.Web/obj` to ignore just that obj folder.

`MyProjects/TED/SourceCode/Presentation/REXI.Web/obj/**/*` to ignore everything in that obj folder. Since empty folders are never committed this amounts to the same as the previous for the most part however it allows you to do:

`!MyProjects/TED/SourceCode/Presentation/REXI.Web/obj/do_commit_this_one` to make an exception where the `do_commit_this_one` file is committed.

As an example, I tend to start my .NET projects with a .gitignore of:

```
logs
obj
bin
*.userprefs
packages/**/*
!packages/repositories.config
geany_run_script.bat
```

And if I'm using SASS on an ASP.NET project, then also:

```
.sass-cache
*.map
*.css
```

As such, it ignores all folders called `logs`, `obj`, `bin` or `.sass-cache` (side-effect folder of SASS). It ignores the contents of all folders called `packages` except for files immediately inside such folders called `repositories.config`. It ignores all files called `geany_run_script.bat` (side-effect file of Geany) and all files ending in `*.map` or `*.css` (I can add exceptions for any static CSS files).

Comment: The best answer about  `.gitignore`! Thanks, bro!

Comment: NP. It's worth reading [the docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) for the full skinny. Conversely, it can be handy to just right-click in explorer if you're using TortoiseGit though while I'm no text-only git purist (or I wouldn't be using TortoiseGit in the first place) I do tend to hand-edit the results to be a bit clearer to grok in one glance.

Answer (score 1):

It worth noting that there is a repository on github that maintain `.gitignore` file for a lot of languages. 
Here is the one that could suit you (where obj, bin and other visual studio or Windows files are ignored) : [visual studio](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore)